# Php email does not send to anyone

Tags: php, html

I have this script in php and i want to send.an email but it does not work for some reason. This script is running on a server on byethost.

I also know there are other similar posts but they didnt help me.

I do not know if the script contains errors or anything else.

```
   <?php
        $to = "somebody@example.com";
        $subject = "My subject";
        $txt = "Hello world!";
       $headers = "From:         
         webmaster@example.com" . "\r\n" .
         "CC: somebodyelse@example.com";

        mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
    ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: The first thing you want to do is confirm whether or not there are errors in the PHP log. You can also have it dynamically write out errors. If I was to make a blind guess, I would say that there's no mailserver tied to your host, so it can't send an email.

Comment: And how do i attach a mail server? Also can you propose a free web hosting (php,mysql) server to provide and an emailserver?

Comment: You have to set the mailserver information in the `php.ini`, or use a 3rd party library, like Pear Mail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-the-gmail-smtp-server-from-a-php-page. There are no free hosts that provide mail servers, its too costly and too easily abused for spam.

Comment: It is possible to use Gmail's front-facing SMTP server to send emails from your Gmail account, however.

Comment: `php.ini` config information: http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php

Comment: Where do i find this php.ini file. Iam not an admin i just have an account to a web hosting server.

Comment: It's different per host. You should create a blank page with this code on it: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and it will tell you the location of your `php.ini` file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, PHP knows how to send an email, but it needs a mail server that actually does the sending.

Some free ones that I use are: https://sendgrid.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) to send emails, email sending library for PHP.